# If the limit points form a finite or countable.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\subset\mathbb R$ and denote by $X'$ the set of limit points of $X$.

Say if it is true or false that:

If  $X'$ is finite or countable, then $X$ is finite or coutable.

I know that if  $X$ is finite or countable , then $X'$ is empty, then finite. But i get stuck there. Thank you

Comment: If $X$ is finite then $X'$ is empty, but if $X$ is countable then $X'$ maybe nonempty. Say $X:=\{\frac 1 n:n\in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468746/uncountable-set-with-exactly-one-limit-point

Answer (score 2):

Any uncountable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has uncountably many limit points.
This is true in any separable metric space. Take $B_n$ a countable open base for the topology (for the reals we can take all open intervals with rational endpoints), and suppose $A$ is uncountable and consider points not in $A'$:

For every $x \in A\setminus A'$, pick $B_n(x)$ such that $B_n(x) \cap A \subset \{x\}$, this can be done as $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.
Clearly $x \neq y$ implies $n(x) \neq n(y)$.

So we have an injection from the set $A \setminus A'$ into the countable set of indices $\mathbb{N}$.
So there are only countably many points of $A$ that are **not** limit points of $A$, and as $A$ is uncountable, $A'$ must be uncountable.

So indeed a set with at most countably many limit points is at most countable as well.