# Every uncountable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ has cardinality of the continuum?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, cardinals

Every uncountable subset $A$  of $\mathbb{R^n}$ has cardinality of the continuum?

Proof: We know that an uncountable subset has uncountable many points that are limit points ( there is a proof in thie link: [Uncountably many points of an uncountable set in a second countable are limit points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17050/uncountably-many-points-of-an-uncountable-set-in-a-second-countable-are-limit-po) )

Let $B=\{ x \in A : x \text{is not limit point of A}\}$. If $B$ is uncountable then there is a point $y\in B$ which is a limit point of $B$ this implies that $y$ is a limit point of $A$, but this is a contradiction because if $y\in B$ then $y$ is a limit point of $A$

Then $B$ is at most countable. Let $P=A\setminus B$ then $P$ is perfect so its cardinality is at least the continuum $c$

So $c \le \text{card}(P) \le \text{card}(A) \le \text{card}(\mathbb{R^n}
) = c$  therefore $A$ has cardinality of the continuum.

But I think this proof is incorrect due to tha fact that I´ve seen this "theorem" but with an extra hypothesis: $A$ must be closed... so I don´t know where is my mistake.

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this problem.

Comment: Why is $P$ perfect? You may test your argument with $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: And interestingly enough, every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is either (at most) countable or has cardinality of the continuum. In particular, this claim is true for any open/closed subsets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is clearly false, as it would imply the Continuum Hypothesis, which cannot be proved from ZFC (as Cohen showed first).

You claim $P$ is perfect and this is in general false. The fact that $B$ is at most countable shows that $|A \setminus B|  = |A|$. Perfect sets are closed. $B \setminus A$ is merely a crowded subset, not a perfect subset.

Recall $P$ is perfect when $P=P'$ where $P'$ is the set of limit points, and whenever $A' \subseteq A$, $A$ is closed, for any $A$. So perfect implies closed. And there is no reason $A \setminus B$ would be closed.

Comment: So if $A$ is closed then $A \setminus B$ would be perfect right? every point of $A \setminus B $ would be a limit point of $A \setminus B$?

Comment: @user128422 yes as $B$ is open in $A$. But then it’s ok. An uncountable closed set has size continuum

Comment: @user128422 It not not true in general that that set would be perfect. $ A - B $ is the set of all limit points of $ A $, which is normally denoted $ A' $. This is not necessarily perfect, even if $ A $ is closed. For example, take $ A = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. Then $ A' = \{0\} $, which is not perfect.

Comment: So how can we use the fact that $A$ is also uncountable to prove this?

Comment: You can use the Cantor Bendixson Theorem, which states that every closed subset of $\mathbb R$ can be written uniquely as a disjoint union of a perfect set and a countable set. From here, the proof you had above will work. The proof of this is nontrivial. One method I know is to use transfinite recursion to essentially iterate the process of $A \mapsto A' $. Alternatively, we say $ x \in A $ is a condensation point of $ A $ if every open neighborhood of $ x $ intersects with $ A $ in an uncountable set. Then let $ \text{kernel}(A) $ be the condensation points of $ A $. That's your perfect set.